# Proper way for keep process running on a container

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I'm not aware if this could be considered as a duplicate since it's a problem for an specific case.

Currently, I have created a docker outside docker image for handling my Jenkins agent which will perform auto restarts without using supervisor as a solution ( lack of python 3.7 support ), and by that, since I'm using `openjdk:slim` as base image and I don't want to install any additional dependencies I opted to compensate the lack of tools like `lsof` and `ps`, or others for checking if the process is running or not, by writing the started process pid on a file which will be used for validating if the process exists or not under the path `/proc/pid/status`. Currently this works and the main reason of creating this solution for handling the auto start of the agents.

But my question is, Is this the best or more appropriated approach?

Please find the following code with the implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

agent_runner() {
    while :
    do
        if [ ! -f "/proc/$(cat /tmp/agent.pid)/status" ]
        then
            curl $JNLP_AGENT_DOWNLOAD_URL -o agent.jar
            java \
            -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300 \
            -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 \
            -jar agent.jar \
            -jnlpUrl $JNLP_AGENT_URL \
            -secret $JENKINS_SECRET \
            -workDir "$JENKINS_WORKDIR" &
            echo $! > /tmp/agent.pid
        else
            :
        fi
        sleep 10
    done
}

while :
do
    if [ cat < /dev/tcp/"$TARGET" ]; then
      echo "Starting Agent"
      agent_runner
    else
      echo "Jenkins master is offline, waiting...."
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Link for the repository: https://github.com/thcp/jenkins-agent-dod

Comment: Why not run the service in a docker swarm service? If the service dies, the swarm will just restart the service on any available host?

Comment: For this specifc scenarios we have our agents under powerpc or x86 vm's, and  for this some projects we can't use docker swarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the main process in the container dies, you should let the container die with it.

Docker and the various layers above it have functionality to restart whole containers.  There is a `docker run --restart` option for the basic Docker CLI, and equivalent Docker Compose option, and restarting dying containers after some backoff is the default behavior for Kubernetes pods.

So, if you just let a container die on its own, you’ll have out-of-the-box support for the container engine to restart itself, without adding any special support into your image; just set the `CMD` to the thing you actually need the container to do and go.  This approach also has the benefit that if you detect your environment has become unstable (“I depend on a database and it’s unreachable”) the process can choose to abort itself and let it be restarted later when hopefully the environment has improved.